# How can i check PEAR mail is installed on my server by shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to install PEAR mail on AWS Elastic Beanstalk applicatoin. By **.ebextension** i can run this command

```
container_commands: 
  01-command: 
    command: pear install mail
  02-command: 
    command: pear install net_smtp
```

I am getting some eorr like **'pear mail is already installed '**
How can i check pear mail is already installed by shell script. So i can check and install.
Or any other way to install without any error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct beanstalk to ignore errors if your command fails:

```
container_commands: 
  01-command: 
    command: pear install mail
    ignoreErrors: true
```